# PHP echoing a table, appending it to a specific element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code, which checks a database and returns some rows to my PHP code containing 4 values (id, playerA, playerB, turn, all INT).

I would like to use that array to build up a table and then append the table to a specific location in the DOM, but i dont know how i could do that.

I could do it another way (get the rows via JS Ajax and then use JS to build and append the table), which i know how, but i dont want to do that.

Is it possible to create a table and append it to a div using php/html/css ?

thanks

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
    $dbManager = DBManager::app();
    $manager = new Manager($_SESSION["userid"]);
    $gameList = $manager->getGames();

    if ($gameList) {
        Debug::log("got active games: ".sizeof($gameList);
    }
    else {
        Debug::log("no games");
    }   
}
else {
        Debug::log("no user id");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    <script src='ajax.js'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="createGame" onclick="createGame()">
        <divid="gameListDiv">
        <div><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT

```
 <?php
    $table = "";

    if ($gameList) {
        foreach ($gameList as $game){       
            $table += "<tr>";
            $table += "<td>";
            $table += $game["name"];
            $table += "</td>";
            $table += "</tr>";
        }

        $table += "</table>";
    }
?>

    <body>
        <input type="form" id="gameName" placeholder="Enter Game Name here"></input>    
        <input type="button" value="createGame" onclick="createGame()"></input>
        <div>
            <span>Active Games</span>
            <?php echo $table; ?>       
        </div>              
        <div><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side. You cannot do what you want to do, in the manner that you want to do it, without JavaScript. Why are you averse to that?

Comment: I want to learn way more PHP than i currently do and i thought it should be possible to do what i want using some kind of echo'ing a large "string".

So you are saying i should get my server-side data via ajax and do it the "old" (for me) way ?

Comment: The only way to do this is to make a round trip to the server to run the PHP. You could do a page reload and use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that the DOM does not yet exist - it is created by the browser, and the browser builds it based on the output of your combined PHP & HTML.

There are many ways to solve this problem without resorting to Ajax calls etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    <script src='ajax.js'></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="createGame" onclick="createGame()">
        <div id="gameListDiv">

        <?php

            if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
                $dbManager = DBManager::app();
                $manager = new Manager($_SESSION["userid"]);
                $gameList = $manager->getGames();

                if ($gameList) {
                    Debug::log("got active games: ".sizeof($gameList);

                    echo '<table style="width:100%">';

                    //assuming we can iterate over the $gameList value
                    foreach($gameList as &$game)
                    {
                        //here i assume that the result returned is an object with these properties - it might be the case that you need to do something like $game['playerA'] or $game->getData('playerA') - i am not sure what database lib you are using.
                        echo '<tr>
                            <td>'.$game->playerA.'</td>
                            <td>'.$game->playerB.'</td>
                            <td>'.$game->turn.'</td>
                          </tr>';
                    }

                    echo '</table>';
                }
                else {
                    Debug::log("no games");
                }   
            }
            else {
                    Debug::log("no user id");
            }

            ?>

        </div>
        <div><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example we are just running the PHP in-line with the HTML.

You could also do something like this if you wanted to keep all of your database logic at the top of the page and not in-line with the HTML:

```
<?php
    /* Database logic here */
    $variable = '<span>this variable could contain any old html that came from the database logic</span>';
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <php echo $variable; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind talking a look at the edit in the OP and tell why its not working ?
It just outputs "0" and appends it after the span, inside the div (not even a table).

sizeof $gameList is 3 and there is a "name" value.

Comment: @C.Finke you are using += which is literally doing a mathematical addition ;-) - if you replace it with .= you should be good to go :) - http://pastebin.com/LM0x6kFG - it won't be the first or last time someone has been done over by the weak typing in PHP

Comment: Well, += works in javascript, i mixed it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build the list before page load, you can just insert something like this where you want the table to go:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($gamelist as $game){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$game.id></td>
        <td><?=$game.playerA></td>
        <td><?=$game.playerB></td>
        <td><?=$game.turn></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

This will work because with PHP, the page hasn't been built and displayed to the user yet when you've got your data in $gamelist. All of your PHP code will be run before the page is actually sent to the user--which means you don't need to "update" the page later, you can just build it now.

If you're looking to collect or update your data after page load (it's unclear from your comments), this is impossible with only PHP as it's a server-side language. You would need to either reload the page or use AJAX for that.